# UWP SemanticZoom Groups binding

Tags: binding, win-universal-app

I've been stuck now for several days because I can't find a way to bind CollectionViewSource to SemanticZoom control (Windows 10 app).

I made it do far that data is shown in the ZoomedIn view.
But I just don't know what else to try to bind groups to ZoomedOut view. It simply doesn't work.
I even made a dummy converter to see what kind of data gets to the data template. But It's kind of useless since it is 'DependencyObject' and I can't even cast it to my object.

Can anyone please help me?

P.S. One additional info: I'm styling my SemanticZoom control in a separate ResourceDictionary and It looks like this:

```
<GridView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Border Height="48"
                Width="144"
                Background="Green"
                BorderThickness="1">
            <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource DoNothing}}"
                         TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
            </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource DoNothing}}"
                       Foreground="Yellow"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
</GridView.ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice example on the GitHub of Microsoft UWP examples.

The given page where it is being used:
https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/5c66da8b7552ad8c3bd665cfad595c7d0bb47059/Samples/XamlUIBasics/cs/AppUIBasics/ControlPages/SemanticZoomPage.xaml

The project you need to download to test drive it:
https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/5c66da8b7552ad8c3bd665cfad595c7d0bb47059/Samples/XamlUIBasics

Take a look and try to track in your code what is going wrong.

Comment: Hello

Sorry for a (very) late reply...
I couldn't answer before :(

Thanks for the link. I've already used few bits from those samples.
But there are very Few (next to zero) people who make templated controls.
And I'm basically searching for a way to create a templated control that can bind different template parts (like grouped header template, zero results template, loading template...)
And I'm having trouble with binding CollectionViewSource.
This is the part that gives me (multiple) headaches...
If there's another way to bind collection to SemanticZoom that's help a lot...